# How to set Custom height for Widget in GridView in Flutter?

Tags: gridview, dart, height, flutter

Even after specifying the height for Container GridView, my code is producing square widgets.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> widgetList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          controller: new ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: widgetList.map((String value) {
            return new Container(
              height: 250.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
                  value,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0,color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the code above is as shown on the left. How can I get a GridView with custom height widget as shown on the right?

[image: output]
[image: Required Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView containing Cards doesn't calculate height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741335/gridview-containing-cards-doesnt-calculate-height-correctly)

Comment: @xskxzr I have to show grid in 1:1 (width:height) ratio but height should have additional 100 pixels extra. eg. How can i do? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

The key is the `childAspectRatio`. This value is use to determine the layout in `GridView`. In order to get the desired aspect you have to set it to the (`itemWidth` / `itemHeight`). The solution would be this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> widgetList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notification bar on Android*/
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
          controller: new ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: widgetList.map((String value) {
            return new Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
                  value,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The GridView doesn't have the property childAspectRatio unless you're doing the count way :-/

Comment: @OliverDixon if you're using `GridView.builder` and `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` then `childAspectRatio` is on the `gridDelegate`

Comment: how to make this height dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic height items - `Staggered grid`
Normal static height items - `Gridview`

Answer (score 54):

### The best answer you'll find

just use

```
 childAspectRatio: (1 / .4)
```

where 1 is width and 0.4 is height customize according to your self
full code here

```
 return GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: (1 / .4),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: List.generate(6, (index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[600],
        child: Row(
          children: [

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Few days ago I came here to find a way to dynamically change height when images are loaded from internet and using `childAspectRatio` cannot do that because its apply to all widget in GridView(same height for each).

This answer may help someone who want different height according to each and every widget content:

I found a package called [Flutter Staggered GridView by Romain Rastel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). Using this package we can do so many things check examples here.

To get what we want we can use `StaggeredGridView.count()` and its property `staggeredTiles:` and for its value you can map all widget and apply `StaggeredTile.fit(2)`.

Example code:

```
StaggeredGridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4, // I only need two card horizontally
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    children: yourList.map<Widget>((item) {
      //Do you need to go somewhere when you tap on this card, wrap using InkWell and add your route
      return new Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             Image.network(item.yourImage),
             Text(yourList.yourText),//may be the structure of your data is different
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),

    //Here is the place that we are getting flexible/ dynamic card for various images
    staggeredTiles: yourList.map<StaggeredTile>((_) => StaggeredTile.fit(2))
        .toList(),
    mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0, // add some space
  ),
);
```

You can find complete example(copy,paste and run) [here](https://gist.github.com/Blasanka/cc46130f325587a9987371b3883f6202).

Comment: staggeredTiles is not defined Sir.

Comment: @NicholasJela syntax may have been changed in latest package. Checkout examples for latest: https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/tree/master/example/lib

Answer (score 24):

All credit goes to @ayRatul on Github for [this answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55290#issuecomment-703117248), which is by far the best and simplest I've seen to achieve a fixed item height in a `GridView`:

Create your own custom delegate:

```
class SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight
    extends SliverGridDelegate {
  /// Creates a delegate that makes grid layouts with a fixed number of tiles in
  /// the cross axis.
  ///
  /// All of the arguments must not be null. The `mainAxisSpacing` and
  /// `crossAxisSpacing` arguments must not be negative. The `crossAxisCount`
  /// and `childAspectRatio` arguments must be greater than zero.
  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight({
    @required this.crossAxisCount,
    this.mainAxisSpacing = 0.0,
    this.crossAxisSpacing = 0.0,
    this.height = 56.0,
  })  : assert(crossAxisCount != null && crossAxisCount > 0),
        assert(mainAxisSpacing != null && mainAxisSpacing >= 0),
        assert(crossAxisSpacing != null && crossAxisSpacing >= 0),
        assert(height != null && height > 0);

  /// The number of children in the cross axis.
  final int crossAxisCount;

  /// The number of logical pixels between each child along the main axis.
  final double mainAxisSpacing;

  /// The number of logical pixels between each child along the cross axis.
  final double crossAxisSpacing;

  /// The height of the crossAxis.
  final double height;

  bool _debugAssertIsValid() {
    assert(crossAxisCount > 0);
    assert(mainAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
    assert(crossAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
    assert(height > 0.0);
    return true;
  }

  @override
  SliverGridLayout getLayout(SliverConstraints constraints) {
    assert(_debugAssertIsValid());
    final double usableCrossAxisExtent =
        constraints.crossAxisExtent - crossAxisSpacing * (crossAxisCount - 1);
    final double childCrossAxisExtent = usableCrossAxisExtent / crossAxisCount;
    final double childMainAxisExtent = height;
    return SliverGridRegularTileLayout(
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
      mainAxisStride: childMainAxisExtent + mainAxisSpacing,
      crossAxisStride: childCrossAxisExtent + crossAxisSpacing,
      childMainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
      childCrossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
      reverseCrossAxis: axisDirectionIsReversed(constraints.crossAxisDirection),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.crossAxisCount != crossAxisCount ||
        oldDelegate.mainAxisSpacing != mainAxisSpacing ||
        oldDelegate.crossAxisSpacing != crossAxisSpacing ||
        oldDelegate.height != height;
  }
}
```

You can then use your custom delegate as so:

```
...
GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: list.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                height: 48.0, //48 dp of height 
...
```

Comment: I have to show grid in 1:1 (width:height) ratio but height should have additional 100 pixels extra. eg. How can i do? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Once you've been doing GridViews for a while, you'll realize this should be adopted by the Flutter team and made a widget of the week.

Answer (score 21):

`crossAxisCount`, `crossAxisSpacing` and screen width determine `width`, and  `childAspectRatio` determines `height`.

I did bit of calculation to figure out relation between them.

```
var width = (screenWidth - ((_crossAxisCount - 1) * _crossAxisSpacing)) / _crossAxisCount;
var height = width / _aspectRatio;
```

---

Full example:

```
double _crossAxisSpacing = 8, _mainAxisSpacing = 12, _aspectRatio = 2;
int _crossAxisCount = 2;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

  var width = (screenWidth - ((_crossAxisCount - 1) * _crossAxisSpacing)) / _crossAxisCount;
  var height = width / _aspectRatio;

  return Scaffold(
    body: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(color: Colors.blue[((index) % 9) * 100]),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: _crossAxisCount,
        crossAxisSpacing: _crossAxisSpacing,
        mainAxisSpacing: _mainAxisSpacing,
        childAspectRatio: _aspectRatio,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 18):

mainAxisExtent: 150,  // here set custom Height You Want

NOT: dynamic Height like: ( size.height or other) is Not Going to Work

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisExtent: 150, // here set custom Height You Want
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Text('150px'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: best and simple answer

Answer (score 11):

[image]

It's working for me.

Example code:

```
var _crossAxisSpacing = 8;
var _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var _crossAxisCount = 2;
var _width = ( _screenWidth - ((_crossAxisCount - 1) * _crossAxisSpacing)) / _crossAxisCount;
var cellHeight = 60;
var _aspectRatio = _width /cellHeight;
```

GridView:

```
         GridView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                          shrinkWrap: false,
                          itemCount: searchList.length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: _crossAxisCount,childAspectRatio: _aspectRatio),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final item = searchList[index];
                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(item.name,maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 15,
                                  height: 15,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: item.isActive == true
                                          ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                          : Colors.red,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(50))),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {

                                },
                              ),
                              elevation: 0.5,
                            );
                          },
                        )
```

Answer (score 9):

**Gridview build with selected highlighted and other unhighlighted**

`mainAxisExtent`: 200 (desired height)

```
GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _images.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisExtent: 200),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedTasteIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: _selectedTasteIndex == index
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(WodlDimens.SPACE10),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                child: Image.asset(_images[index]),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                _tastes[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: _selectedTasteIndex == index
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                      //return Image.network(images[index]);
                    },
                  ))
```

Comment: you're damn right about that..

Answer (score 8):

You can use mainAxisExtent instead of childAspectRatio

```
    GridView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: resumes.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisExtent: 256,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(),
              ),
```

Comment: This was the answer i was actually looking for, it actually worked like magic

Answer (score 6):

Well, the first solution I could see everywhere was using `childAspectRatio`

But aspect ratio was giving different height of the container inside GridView for different screen sizes devices!

But then, I finally got the perfect solution:

Instead of using `childAspectRatio`, Use `mainAxisExtent` which defines the fixed height of the container

```
GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          mainAxisSpacing: CommonDimens.MARGIN_20,
          crossAxisSpacing: CommonDimens.MARGIN_20,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisExtent: 152,
          // childAspectRatio: 1.1, DONT USE THIS when using mainAxisExtent
        ),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: itemList.length,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (_, position) => itemList[position],
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `childAspectRatio` property in the `gridDelegate` of a `GridView`:

```
gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 2/1.6  // try to fiddle with this ratio
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                mainAxisSpacing: 15,
              ),
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
childAspectRatio: .7 (or something you can change it and update your view)
```

in GridView.builder

use like this

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            childAspectRatio: .7,
          ),
```

in GridView.count use like this

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    childAspectRatio: .7,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the GridView, use this code:

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
crossAxisCount: 3, //Number of columns you want
childAspectRatio: (1 / .4) //height & width for the GridTile
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this line in GridView.count

childAspectRatio: 2/4,

Comment: Explain what it does and where you got the answer?

Comment: The childAspectRatio: 2/4 means 2 parts of width and 4 parts of height . I've used it in my code and it's working pretty fine . You can also use childAspectRatio in gridview.count according to your requirement to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

The only built-in easy solution is, to use `childAspectRatio` and set it to something like `1 / .6` or `1 / .7` depending on your widget size. By default, Flutter GridView.count sets height and width the same size and it causes excess padding if the design requires different shape output. With `childAspectRatio` way we can assign half value of the width to the height and get what we want to achieve.

```
GridView.count(
                      childAspectRatio: (1 / .7), // this line is the one determines the width-height ratio
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: gScreenWidth / 40,
                      mainAxisSpacing: gScreenWidth / 40,
                                           children: List.generate(
                          yourList.length, (index) {
                        return Center(
                            child: Container(
                               child: Text('Hello World. Finally I fixed the height issue'))),
},
)),
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was one of my problems, But I found that if we put the repetitive widget in the SingleChildScrollView widget, the height of the repetitive widget will be in the minimum size!

that's it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Height Grid View to easily manage the grid view.

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_height_grid_view

Answer (score 0):

So because I had some issues with grid view and I really didn't like aspect ration (it does not work properly in flutter web) I came up by creating "custom grid view". You can edit these widget with your needs. Each child takes the height that it needs, but you can edit it and add a default height or something.

CustomGridView:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomGridView({
    super.key,
    required this.crossAxisCount,
    required this.length,
    required this.widgetOfIndex,
    this.crossAxisSpacing = 0,
    this.mainAxisSpacing = 0,
    this.physics,
    this.shrinkWrap = false,
  });

  final int crossAxisCount;
  final int length;
  final double crossAxisSpacing;
  final double mainAxisSpacing;
  final Widget Function(int index) widgetOfIndex;
  final ScrollPhysics? physics;
  final bool shrinkWrap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: physics,
      shrinkWrap: shrinkWrap,
      itemCount: (length / crossAxisCount).ceil(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int listIndex) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            crossAxisCount,
            (int index) {
              return Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: index < crossAxisCount - 1 ? crossAxisSpacing / 2 : 0,
                    left: index > 0 ? crossAxisSpacing / 2 : 0,
                    bottom: mainAxisSpacing,
                  ),
                  child: listIndex * crossAxisCount + index < length ? widgetOfIndex(listIndex * crossAxisCount + index) : const SizedBox(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is how you can call it:

```
CustomGridView(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 16,
          length: _apartments.length,
          widgetOfIndex: (int index) {
            return YourWidget(_apartments[index]);
          },
        ),
```

For Sliver grid view you can get this,

CustomSliverGridView:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSliverGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomSliverGridView({
    super.key,
    required this.crossAxisCount,
    required this.length,
    required this.widgetOfIndex,
    this.crossAxisSpacing = 0,
    this.mainAxisSpacing = 0,
  });

  final int crossAxisCount;
  final int length;
  final double crossAxisSpacing;
  final double mainAxisSpacing;
  final Widget Function(int index) widgetOfIndex;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int listIndex) {
          return Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
              crossAxisCount,
              (int index) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: index < crossAxisCount - 1 ? crossAxisSpacing / 2 : 0,
                      left: index > 0 ? crossAxisSpacing / 2 : 0,
                      bottom: mainAxisSpacing,
                    ),
                    child: listIndex * crossAxisCount + index < length ? widgetOfIndex(listIndex * crossAxisCount + index) : const SizedBox(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: (length / crossAxisCount).ceil(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally you can get the custom sliver grid view like this:

```
 CustomSliverGridView(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                    length: _apartments.length,
                    widgetOfIndex: (int index) {
                      return YourWidget(_apartments[index]);
                    },
                  )
```