# GridView overflowing with multiple items added to the grid spot

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, overflow

We have a grid view which is basically 3 columns with some additional in each of the columns but the last elements seem to be getting overflown

```
GridView.count(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 35,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: List.generate(3, (index) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            minRadius: 30,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Text(
                            'Name',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(
                            '$index',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: You need to increase the height of your widget. [like this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405123/how-to-set-custom-height-for-widget-in-gridview-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

try to use .

```
   SizedBox(
height= // your option , 
child : // your Widegt,
)
```

Comment: that error is overflowed from the bottom not left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Column wih "SingleChildScrollView"

Comment: we dont want it to scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
crossAxisSpacing: 35  This is the causing problem
```

#### Explanation:

Say if you have `screen width` of 300 and you have 3 columns of `80` width each.

This spacing would cause `80 + 35 + 80 + 35 + 80  = 310` which is `10px` extra.

#### Solution:

Replace `crossAxisSpacing` by providing `padding` inside the `grid items`

#### Output after setting `crossAxisSpacing = 0` :

[image]